# Spring Boot 3.1 Upgrade - Disable CSRF in Integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, csrf, spring-boot-test

I am receiving a 403 error in integration tests after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.5. How can I disable CSRF in the test?

I tried adding `csrf.disable()`, but I am still receiving a 403 error.

Any annotations needed in the test?

I also tried adding `@WebMvcTest` and `.with(csrf())` as well, but no luck.

```java
  @Bean
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
    http
      .addFilterBefore(new AuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(r -> config))
      .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
      .headers(headers -> headers
        .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin()))
      .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
      .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/test").hasRole("xxx")
        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/test")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().denyAll()
      ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
  }
  
  @Test
  void demo() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post(url).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).content(body)).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

Comment: you didn't explain how exactly you use `.with(csrf())` but according to the official Spring documentation [Testing with CSRF Protection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/csrf.html) this should be the right way.

Comment: Exactly used like mvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf()))  .

Comment: .perform(post("/").with(csrf()))   is to enable the csrf but I want to disable it.

Comment: So I understood that you have enabled CSRF in your application, but as your tests fail, you want to disable it for the tests but in your application? The methods on the page show you how to mock it, so you should be able to test the application with enabled CSRF.

Comment: I have disabled csrf in the security config however the integration test fails with 403 . Hence looking for a solution to disable csrf in the test as well .

Comment: Can you share the code for a sample test and your security config?

Comment: The code is updated in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hasAuthority` instead `hasRole` in security configuration `configure()` method should solve your issue:

```
//...
.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("ACTUATOR")
.requestMatchers("/api/v1/test").hasAuthority("xxx")
//...
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck. The entire security config class was disabled and still, the test returns 403. Not sure what else causing this issue. If I revert the change to Spring Boot 2.7 then everything works fine. I have removed WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and implemented it as per Spring Boot migration instructions . Are any other changes needed?